# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a non-UEFI compliant motherboard?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb, bios

I'm building a computer using some hand me down parts. My old motherboard supports EFI and BIOS, but does NOT support UEFI (too old, its a 2012 era system). Every time I have tried to make a bootable USB and install Ubuntu, I end up in a Grub Rescue menu upon restart (or if I manage to repair Grub, then I end up with errors about the kernel panic and all my research points to the notion that my bootable USB is bad.) This has been happening for 2 weeks. Doesn't matter if I use Rufus or Etcher. I need some explicit instructions because none of my peicemeal solutions I've found so far have worked.

Any advice on how to install Ubuntu 20.04 on this old motherboard? Or should I just eat it and get a new one?

**Current Hardware:**

Processor (old): AMD FX8150 chip, 8 cores 
RAM (old): Corsair Vengence 2x 4GB DDR3 1600 MHz, 1x 8GB DDR3/ 1600 MHz
Motherboard (old): Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3
Hard Drive (new): Segate Barracuda 4TB 5400 RPM Sata III 6GB/s 3.5" 
Graphics Card (new): ASUS GeForce GT710

Comment: EFI is UEFI, just old version. But you need some UEFI/BIOS settings and boot parameters. Older versions, but similar issues. Some Gigabyte boards need acpi=off boot parameter also
Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 and 64bit Xubuntu 16.04 LTS install
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2370503
 GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel - IOMMU GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242023 And nomodeset for nVidia card.

Comment: You could try flashing an Ubuntu 20.04 image file to your hard drive, (It will overwrite the entire drive), see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi. The method is similar for a HDD as for a USB. Boot from a persistent Ubuntu USB with the .img file located on it and use Disks to "Restore" the image to the HDD. The resulting disk will boot in either Legacy or UEFI computers.

Comment: Gigabyte is known for putting the hybrid EFI BIOS on their boards, mainly used for larger hard drive support.  I have used several Gigabyte boards and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on them in normal Legacy mode.  I actually prefer Legacy over UEFI since Legacy in my opinion, actually gives more control.  And if I remember right, there really isn't a way to set the BIOS to boot UEFI other than just selecting the proper boot drive as your first drive.